# Changing ftp upload location

Tags: java, upload, ftp

So I'm uploading a file to my VPS (Linux Centos 5 64 bit) via FTP using Java. The code I'm using to upload to my VPS is

```
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    FileInputStream fis = null;

    try {
        client.connect(serverip);
        client.login("user, pass);
        client.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

//  Create an InputStream of the file to be uploaded
        String filename = Shared.saveLocation + Shared.saveAs;
        fis = new FileInputStream(filename);

//  Store file to server
        client.storeFile(Shared.saveAs, fis);
        client.logout();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (fis != null) {
                fis.close();
            }
            client.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Now the code is working but what I want is to change where on the VPS it uploads the file to. Right now it's

> serverip/HERE

I have some files so want to change it to

> serverip/file/HERE

How can I go about doing so?

Comment: Nobody knows how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`changeCurrentWorkingDirectory()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#changeWorkingDirectory%28java.lang.String%29) method to change to the desired directory. Once you're in there, you can write the file using [`storeFile`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#storeFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.InputStream%29) just like before.

`changeCurrentWorkingDirectory` returns true if the directory change was successful, otherwise it returns false. It takes a string which interpreted as the directory path. If the path starts with a slash, it's interpreted as absolute path starting at the ftproot directory. Otherwise it's interpreted as relative path.

Revised code could look something like this:

```
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
FileInputStream fis = null;

try 
{
    client.connect(serverip);
    client.login("user, pass);
    client.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

    // change directory to serverip/file/
    if (client.changeWorkingDirectory("/file"))
    {       
        // Create an InputStream of the file to be uploaded
        String filename = Shared.saveLocation + Shared.saveAs;
        fis = new FileInputStream(filename);

        // Store file to server
        client.storeFile(Shared.saveAs, fis);
    }
    client.logout();
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
finally 
{
    try
    {
        if (fis != null) 
        {
            fis.close();
        }
        client.disconnect();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks. I'll award you the bounty after 19 hours because that's when it'll let me.